# uncheck debug mode in Websphere Application Server through script

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

i need to uncheck Websphere Aplication Server debug mode through script,I'm WAS 7.0 server running on Windows 2008R2 64bit.

Comment: Welcome on SO *user3751939*! Please give some more information and tell us what you did to solve your problem. Additionaly have an eye on the *Tour* in the help menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should run wsadmin in your profile bin directory:

```
wsadmin.bat -lang jython -user *** -password ***
```

and in wsadmin promt:

```
AdminTask.setJVMProperties('[-nodeName node01 -serverName server1 -debugMode false]')
AdminConfig.save()
```

substituting node and server name, and select true of false.

And you can run this script as a file. Just add this two lines to, e.g. debugOff.py and call it as

```
wsadmin.bat -lang jython -user *** -password *** -f [real-path-to]/debugOff.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable debug mode even if Websphere is shut down. Open this file:

```
/usr/IBM/AppServer/profiles/<my profile>/config/cells/<my cell>/nodes/<my node>/servers/<server>/server.xml
```

Search for node `jvmEntries`, attribute `debugMode="true"` and set it to `false`. Start Websphere.